# How do I add/edit CSS attributes in IE8 running on a VM?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, virtual-machine

If I go into the dev tools, I can see the CSS but I can't seem to be able to add any or edit the current CSS like I can in Chrome or Firebug. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found how to do it:
Go into the CSS panel
Click your stylesheet from the drop down
Find the portion of CSS you want to edit/add to
Then click add rule

Answer (score 0):

Not super useful, but you can edit the HTML and add a style in-line.  So for instance you have:

```
<li class="something">
```

off to the right dev tools will show you what "something" is, and let you turn it (and it's attributes) off or on via the check-boxes.

But if you wanted to add a new attribute, I don't know how to add it to "something", but you can edit the html on the left side of the dev tools window to be something like:

```
<li class="something" style="text-align:center;">
```